# Transparently doing .translate with str and unicode objects

Tags: python, unicode

This is the implementation I am using to abstract away the differences for `.translate` between unicode and str:

```
import types
from string import maketrans

def str_translate(txt, inchars, outchars, deletechars):
    if inchars : transtab = maketrans(inchars, outchars)
    else       : transtab = None
    return txt.translate(transtab, deletechars)


def maketrans_u(inchars, outchars, deletechars):
    '''Create a translation table for unicode. We assume that we
    want to map one inchar to one outchar (but the actual unicode.translate function
    is more powerful: it can also map one inchar to a unicode string)
    We assume deletechars and inchars do not overlap (no checking done!)'''
    if inchars : transtab = dict((ord(inchar), ord(outchar)) for inchar, outchar in zip(inchars, outchars))
    else       : transtab = { }
    # Now map the deletechars to None
    for char in deletechars:
        transtab[ord(char)] = None
    return transtab


def unicode_translate(txt, inchars, outchars, deletechars):
    transtab = maketrans_u(inchars, outchars, deletechars)
    return txt.translate(transtab)


def translate(txt, inchars=None, outchars=None, deletechars=None):
    t = type(txt)
    if   t == types.StringType  : return str_translate(txt, inchars, outchars, deletechars)
    elif t == types.UnicodeType : return unicode_translate(txt, inchars, outchars, deletechars)
    else                        : raise Exception('Not supported type %s' % (t))


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    a = 'abc%=def'
    deletechars = '=%'
    print translate(a, deletechars=deletechars)
```

Here I am losing some of the power of the `unicode.translate` (namely, translating one character to a string), but at least I have a uniform interface that I can use to translate unicode and plain strings, without having to care about the type.

What I do not like is:

- this implementation relies in checking the type of the string in order to call the right function
- I can not do `txt.translate(...)` (I must do `translate(txt, ...)`, which means I can not chain function calls like `txt[:50].translate(...)`

Is there a better way to implement a transparent `.translate`?

Comment: I think this might go better on [code review stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this implementation relies in checking the type of the string in order to call the right function

Well, what else *could* it do? You want to do different things for different types, and you can't monkeypatch the types to do it in dot-syntax OO style, so how can you automatically dispatch on types? What you're looking for is *external dispatch*. Python can do this in 3.4+ (only dispatching on the first argument, not all arguments like CLOS or Dylan… although there are multiple-dispatch libraries on PyPI) with [`singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch), and there's [a backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/singledispatch) on PyPI that works back to 2.6. So, you can do this:

```
from singledispatch import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def translate(txt, inchars=None, outchars=None, deletechars=None):
    raise Exception('Not supported type %s' % (t))

@translate.register(str)
def translate(txt, inchars=None, outchars=None, deletechars=None):
    return str_translate(txt, inchars, outchars, deletechars)

@translate.register(unicode)
def translate(txt, inchars=None, outchars=None, deletechars=None):
    return unicode_translate(txt, inchars, outchars, deletechars)
```

Notice also that I just used `str` and `unicode` instead of [`types.StringType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.StringType) and `types.UnicodeType`. As the docs say, those types are just aliases, and they aren't really necessary. All they do is make your code less backward-compatible. (And they don't help for forward compatibility with 3.x; 3.0 just removed the unnecessary aliases instead of making `StringType` and `UnicodeType` both aliases for `str` and adding a `BytesType`…)

If you don't want to use a library off PyPI or implement the same thing yourself, and instead want manual type-switching, you probably want `isinstance` rather than `type(x) ==`.

---

> I can not do txt.translate(...) (I must do translate(txt, ...)

That's true; you can't monkeypatch `str` and `unicode`. But so what?

> which means I can not chain function calls like txt[:50].translate(...)

Sure, but you can chain function calls like `translate(txt[:50], …).rstrip().split(':')`. While that might look anti-idiomatic in a "everything-is-a-method" language like Java or Ruby, it's perfectly fine in Python. Especially since it's pretty rare to chain more than 2 or 3 calls in Python anyway. After all, the next thing after that `split` is going to have to be a `map` call or a comprehension, and those aren't done by methods in Python.

---

> Here I am losing some of the power of the `unicode.translate` (namely, translating one character to a string)

Yes, that's pretty much inherent in the lowest-common-denominator design. And so is some performance loss. `str.translate` and `unicode.translate` aren't really doing exactly the same thing. The former is a table-based translation, because that's a great optimization when you only have 256 possible values, but it does mean you give up some flexibility and power. The latter is a dict-based translation, because a table would be a pessimization for 1.1 million values, but that means you get some extra flexibility and power.

So, here, you're giving up the performance of `str.translate` (especially since you have to build the `transtab` on the fly for each translation), and the flexibility of `unicode.translate`, to get the worst of both worlds.

If you actually know the encodings of your `str` strings (and they actually do represent text—after all, `str.translate` can also be useful for binary data…), you could instead write this by just `s.decode(encoding).translate(…).encode(encoding)`. But then if you know the encodings, you might as well just have `unicode` instead of `str` in the first place.

---

But I think a better solution might to be wrap up `maketrans` in a way that returns a tuple of two tables for `str`, and a tuple of one dict for `unicode`. Then you can just call the native `s.translate(*transtab)` for either, instead of wrapping `translate`.

Unfortunately, you can't use `singledispatch` for this, because any of the arguments may be `None`, which means we're back to explicit type-switching.

```
def maketrans(inchars, outchars, deletechars):
    if isinstance(inchars, str) or isinstance(deletechars, str):
        return maketrans_s(inchars, outchars, deletechars)
    elif isinstance(inchars, unicode) or isinstance(deletechars, unicode):
        return maketrans_u(inchars, outchars, deletechars)
    raise Exception('Not supported type %s' % (t))

def maketrans_s(inchars, outchars, deletechars):
    if inchars: transtab = maketrans(inchars, outchars)
    else: transtab = None
    return transtab, deletechars

def maketrans_u(inchars, outchars, deletechars):
    # The if was unnecessary here; if inchars is empty, the zip
    # will be too, so you'll get {} as the result. Also notice
    # no ord(outchar); this means you _can_ use Unicode strings
    # when you know the string is Unicode.
    transtab = dict((ord(inchar), outchar) for inchar, outchar in zip(inchars, outchars))
    for char in deletechars:
        transtab[ord(char)] = None
    return transtab,
```

Now you can do this:

```
transtab = maketrans(inchars, outchars, deletechars)
return s.translate(*transtab).rstrip().split(':')
```

---

But really, I'm not sure where this would be useful in the first place. How can you even call `maketrans` or `translate` without knowing whether your `inchars` and `deletechars` are `str` or `unicode`?

Comment: Wow, thanks for your great ideas. I'll let it through my head for a bit.

Comment: Re "How can you even call maketrans or translate without knowing whether your inchars and deletechars are str or unicode": in my (limited) usecase, inchars. outchars and deletechars are all str, but txt can be either str or unicode.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide: Are they guaranteed to be all ASCII? Because if you try to translate, say, `'é'`, what happens will depend on whether that's a Latin-1 `é` or a UTF-8 `é`. (In fact, even with pure ASCII you can have that problem, because not every encoding is 100% ASCII-compatible—e.g., JIS encodes the yen symbol to the ASCII backslash… But usually you can ignore that and just pretend that every encoding is ASCII-compatible; you can't ignore the fact that every encoding is not whatever-your-default-charset-is-compatible.)